# Postfix send mail from a specific IP for specific mails

Tags: postfix

I have a server which has 2 public IPs. When sending an e-mail (With PHPMailer to installed postfix) it uses one of the IPs to bind and send the message.

Is there a way to tell postfix to use the other IP, but not for all mails?

Comment: You need to use `sender_dependent_default_transport_maps`. Have a look at the [docs](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html). This is quite extensive and not _very_ easy to implement.

Comment: Worked with http://www.iredmail.org/docs/send.out.email.from.specified.ip.addresses.html

Comment: Alright nice, write an answer and mark it as accepted. My "quite extensive" was meant for many different hosts / IPs, maybe even via regex. If you only need two IPs or domains, it's quite simple.

Comment: Could you please provide some simple example of configuration for 2 domain names and two IPs?

Answer (score 1):

To bind your postfix to a specific IP, add to main.cf this line

```
smtp_bind_address = 192.168.1.200
```

Then restart your postfix

This can be used in the master.cf also, read more about it on postfix site:

http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_bind_address